# VMWare Get-Tpm2EndorsementKey Error

Tags: vmware, vcenter

I am trying to set up Trusted Authority on my Dell Poweredge R730XD Vcenter but am getting a TPM error when running the following command:

```
Get-Tpm2EndorsementKey - VMHost 192.168.15.11
```

I have been following the instructions in the [VMware documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-4472E799-189D-48C6-83D0-1D77785BC8A7.html#GUID-4472E799-189D-48C6-83D0-1D77785BC8A7)

When I run this command however I am getting the following error which I cant seem to get any information on.

> Get-Tpm2EndorsementKey: 14/12/2023 12:57:52 PM  Get-Tpm2EndorsementKey
> com.vmware.vapi.std.errors.error {'messages':
> [com.vmware.vapi.std.localizable_message {'id':
> com.vmware.vcenter.trusted_infrastructure.hosts.hardware.tpm.host_not_support,
> 'default_message': Host host-10:bf813356-9e3d-456d-a1db-e0d05ef4c197
> does not support the operation through vCenter vAPI., 'args': [],
> 'params': [map-entry {'key': host, 'value':
> com.vmware.vapi.std.localization_param {'s':
> host-10:bf813356-9e3d-456d-a1db-e0d05ef4c197, 'dt': , 'i': , 'd': ,
> 'l': , 'format': , 'precision':}}], 'localized': Host
> host-10:bf813356-9e3d-456d-a1db-e0d05ef4c197 does not support the
> operation through vCenter vAPI.}], 'data': , 'error_type': ERROR}

TPM is enabled in the BIOS.

When I run the same command on the ESXI host directly rather than the Vcenter I get the following error:

> WARNING: The Get-Tpm2EndorsementKey with ESXi connection session is deprecated. Please connect to the VC directly to run the cmdlet.
> Get-Tpm2EndorsementKey: 14/12/2023 12:57:01 PM  Get-Tpm2EndorsementKey          An error occurred while performing a TPM operation.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I assume the host machine has enabled TPM and its otherwise functioning? What’s odd is that the “does not support the operation through vCenter vAPI” can’t be found anywhere

Comment: You are correct. TPM is enabled and the machine is fully functional in every other way.

i know I cant find any reference to this error code, anywhere

Comment: [This](https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/rack-servers/poweredge-r750-tpm-20-vmware/647f9c18f4ccf8a8de022658) is a similar error but not an exact match and unlikely related

Comment: Can you try [these](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/78249) instructions?

Comment: @Ramhound Those instructions won't work as the third step creating the tpm2 variable:
'$tmp2 = Get-Tpm2EndorsementKey -VMHost $vmhost'
 gives the same warning listed in the original post:

'WARNING: The Get-Tpm2EndorsementKey with ESXi connection session is deprecated. Please connect to the VC directly to run the cmdlet.
Get-Tpm2EndorsementKey: 14/12/2023 2:05:58 PM   Get-Tpm2EndorsementKey          An error occurred while performing a TPM operation.'